# Can't extract two fields out of some text using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to fetch three fields from some text using regex. The value of fields that I'm after are `PLAN`,`TITLE` and `REFERENCE`. I can extract the value of `REFERENCE` but I'm stuck with the other two fields. How can I get the value of `PLAN` and `TITLE` using regex?

I've tried with (it gives me the reference number):

```
import re

item_str = """
S
PLAN             SHORT                                         TITLE
0030 278 592     0420091;16                                    052 400 228

REFERENCE: 042 420 626
"""
ref = re.findall(r"REFERENCE:\s+(.*)",item_str)[0]
print(ref)
```

Comment: Where is the TITLE value?

Comment: Slide to the right @barny.

Comment: Lol. Completely unobvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this example ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IKTOlf/3)):

```
import re

item_str = """
S
PLAN             SHORT                                         TITLE
0030 278 592     0420091;16                                    052 400 228

REFERENCE: 042 420 626
"""

print( re.findall(r'(?=^PLAN).*?(^[\d ]+?)\s{2,}.*\s{2,}(\d.*?$).*?^REFERENCE:\s*([\d ]+)', item_str, flags=re.M|re.S) )
```

Prints:

```
[('0030 278 592', '052 400 228', '042 420 626')]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Andrej. However, it misses one field which is `TITLE`. The value of `SHORT` is not I was trying to capture.

Comment: Broken link - ??

Comment: @SMTH Updated the regex.